# Which Python testing framework to use?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have lots of directories in which there are python files. All are plain python files. I have not used any sort of framework for the same. I want to test those py files from one central location. I should just fire one command and all the *_test.py files from each and every directory should be invoked.
So, is there any ready tool or framework available for my requirement ?

I an looking for PyUnit for testing plain py files. And thinking of writing one shell script which will invoke all these *_test.py files by using regex to match the file names.

Anyone can suggest any other approach. You are always welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) does all of this. Just `cd` to the root of your tree of Python files, and run

```
nosetests
```

Nose [finds test files](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html) using a [regex](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html) (basically the word `test` or `Test` present in the name):

> If it looks like a test, it’s a test. Names of directories, modules,
>   classes and functions are compared against the testMatch regular
>   expression, and those that match are considered tests. Any class that
>   is a unittest.TestCase subclass is also collected, so long as it is
>   inside of a module that looks like a test.